# Simple examples of applications of converse, contrapositive and inverse used in mathematical proofs rather than logic.

Tags: soft-question, proof-writing

While learning simple logic in high school, I remember learning about converse, contrapositive and inverse (maybe some others as well).

Yet, I don't seem to recall their usage for proofs  (only contradiction is what I remember being used in number theory e.g $\sqrt 2$ is irrational).

Can anyone point to some examples of their usage in mathematics or even natural language to see for example the distinction between converse and inverse and their applications in theorem proving?

Comment: The contrapositive can be used in proofs. Take the following example: If $n^2$ is odd, $n$ is odd. It is easier to prove the contrapositive here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the contrapositive to prove something.

- A function is 
  $1-1$ if $f(x)=f(y)→x=y.$
  To prove the above theorem it is sufficient to prove its contrapositive i.e.
- A function is $1-1$ if $x\not=y→f(x)\not=f(y)$